# Esper js expression declaration

Tags: complex-event-processing, esper

I am following the example in [Esper documentation](http://esper.espertech.com/release-8.8.0/reference-esper/html_single/index.html#script-examples) to create an expression following js dialect

Here's my EPL declaration

```
expression float js:IOU(xBottom1,yBottom1, xTop1, yTop1, xBottom2, yBottom2, xTop2, yTop2) [
    IOU(xBottom1,yBottom1, xTop1, yTop1, xBottom2, yBottom2, xTop2, yTop2);
    function IOU(xBottom1,yBottom1, xTop1, yTop1, xBottom2, yBottom2, xTop2, yTop2) {
    //get the bottom left and top right points of the intersection triangle
    var xIntersection1 = Math.max(xBottom1,xBottom2);
    var yIntersection1 = Math.max(yBottom1,yBottom2);
    var xIntersection2 = Math.min(xTop1,xTop2);
    var yIntersection2 = Math.min(yTop1,yTop2);

    var interArea = (Math.max(0, xIntersection2 - xIntersection1 +1) * Math.max(0, yIntersection2 - yIntersection1 +1));
    var box1Area = (Math.max(0, xTop1 - xBottom1 +1) * Math.max(0, yTop1 - yBottom1 +1));
    var box2Area = (Math.max(0, xTop2 - xBottom2 +1) * Math.max(0, yTop2 - yBottom2 +1));

    var iou = interArea / parseFloat(box1Area+box2Area-interArea);

    return iou;
   }
]
```

However, I get a compilation error as `Incorrect syntax near 'IOU' at line 2 column 4 [expression float js:IOU(xBottom1,yBottom1, xTop1, yTop1, xBottom2, yBottom2, xTop2, yTop2)...`

I am not sure what is missing and if there are examples in Esper Github for using expressions? Do I need to configure the compiler somehow? This is not mentioned in the respective chapter, Chapter 19 of the documentation.

Just to clarify, I tried even with a single-line JS script and I verified the above JS function. So, I believe that it is related to how to define the script in EPL not the syntax itself within the respective dialect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standalone expression syntax is "create expression". Since I don't see anything else I presume you want to do a standalone expression and so its missing "create".
And when its not a standalone expression the syntax is "expression ... select ...".

[Here is a link to one of the regression tests.](https://github.com/espertechinc/esper/blob/master/regression-lib/src/main/java/com/espertech/esper/regressionlib/suite/epl/script/EPLScriptExpression.java)